# Open chooser with Lock Screen in it

Tags: android, android-intent, lockscreen

I want to create a chooser where to find the LockScreen/HomeScreen. Something like this:

[image]

I tried like this:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_BACKGROUND);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
```

with different actions, but nothing seems to work. For the screenshot I selected a photo from gallery and then "set as" option. I also downloaded some apps that have same feature, so I suppose it is possible. I just don't figure out how?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe this solution will suit You:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17408441/6507689

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, it's not what I want, as that approach opens me a Launcher chooser, where I find none of Home/LockScreen ....